# Combining Directories in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, filesystems

Is it possible to set up a directory which contains:

```
File A
File B
File C
```

then create a second directory that initially contains:

```
File D
File E
```

is it possible, I can modify the second directory to show:

```
File A
File B
File C
File D
File E
```

but not by copying the files, so that if they are changed in the first directory, the changes are accessible instantly in the second directory.

Additionally, when it comes to putting files there, it would be nice to have an option of always to one directory, or choose, but I suppose if necessary any new files created in the second directory would be stored in the second directory, and if the file needed to exist in the first directory as well, then it could be copied to the first directory.

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but not by a "directory junction". You'll need a link for each file. I.e. `Dir2\File A` should be a link to `Dir1\File A`. As a corollary, when you add new files to `Dir1\` they won't automatically show up in `Dir2`.

Comment: So I would need some sort of monitor to be running that will update the second directory with junction links to the files and directories in the first directory if I wanted to do that?

Comment: Yes, but this can be done efficiently with a file system watcher.

Answer (score 1):

A user-friendly way of doing this is using the [Library feature](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/libraries-faq) in Windows.